# Can't connect to MySQL 5.5 with SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl, replication, rhel6

I am trying to get MySQL SSL replication setup for two brand new RHEL 6.6 x64 servers. I have replication working without SSL, but I can't get it set up with SSL, and can't connect directly using SSL either. I have tried connecting from both the master and the slave with **mysql -h x.x.x.x -u root -p --ssl=1 --ssl-ca=ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem**, as well as locally (Windows + MySQL Workbench), no matter what, I get:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

Since RHEL came with MySQL 5.1, I upgraded both master and slave to 5.5 per https://webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/, **mysql --version** for both now shows "Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1"

Then I tried to set up SSL with self-signed certs and replication based on the tutorial at https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-mysql-database-replication-with-ssl-encryption-on-centos-5.4

I made sure to use different Common Names for all three certificates, and **openssl verify** confirms that both client-cert.pem and server-cert.pem are "OK" when tested against ca.pem.

But I still get the SSL connection error above no matter what I try. No errors in the master's error log, nothing else I can see that would be causing the failure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure the CN in the CA and Server certs are different

Comment: I did, all three are different (ca.domain.com, server.domain.com, client.domain.com).

Comment: How did you configure the server? This information is not in your question.

Comment: Configure like how? The my.cnf file?
`[mysqld]
...
ssl
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/newcerts/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/newcerts/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/newcerts/server-key.pem
server-id = 1
log_bin  = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = 100M`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the Common Name of your CA certificate and Server certificates are different

If your certificates were generated using `openssl` with a version greater than 1.0 and are RSA, reformat your keys using the following: `openssl rsa -in key-from-openssl-1.pem -out pkcs1-yassl-compatible-key.pem` (*replace filenames as appropriate*). The reason for this is that the key format is not compatible with `yaSSL`, which is what MySQL uses for SSL. Alternatively, open the pem files with an editor, and replace `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` with `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`

Comment: CN's of all three certs are different (ca.domain.com, server.domain.com, client.domain.com).

Comment: Certs were generated with openssl 1.0.1e-fips with RSA. I tried the reformat command on server-key.pem and client-key.pem, and verified that the tops and bottoms of the pem files are now showing `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` and `END RSA PRIVATE KEY`. I restarted MySQL service and tried again, still getting the same error.