# MySQL SSL error, only when connecting from windows/osX

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

I am using openssl to generate ssl certificates that I am using to connect to mysql with SSL encryption.  This works fine while I am connecting from the local host environement (even when I connect over the servers public IP, I have also connected successfully from the web server boxes).  However, When I try to connect from my local dev machine I get an SSL errror.

When connecting from hosting platform

```
mysql -u metrics -p -h 45.33.x.x --ssl-key=client-key.pem --ssl-ca=ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 136 ...
```

When connecting from Mac dev machine,  I used scp to copy the cert/key files to my dev machine

```
mysql -u metrics -h 45.33.x.x -p --ssl-key=client-key.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-ca=ca.pem
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

Here is what I have done to try to solve this problem

1. I have generated checksums of cert/key/ca on the server and local machine, they are identical
2. I have looked at [Can't connect to MySQL 5.5 with SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/698343/cant-connect-to-mysql-5-5-with-ssl) server fault question neither idea solved the problem
3. I have [debugged SSL](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/08/debugging-mysql-ssl-problems/) by starting the openSSL server (on the mysql server) and connecting from my local machine, once again no problems.

If it makes a difference the servers are all running ubuntu 14.04 with openSSL "OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014" and I am connecting from osX 10.10.4 with openSSL "OpenSSL 1.0.2c 12 Jun 2015"

So any ideas?

Comment: If possible, it's worth to add the output of `openssl x509 -text -in FILE` for CA, server and client certificate (just mask sensitive parts like an e-mail, domain, etc.). MySQL server- and client-side config files could also help.

Comment: One thing I would try is [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench) and see if it can maybe suggest (in more detail) any network problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a cipher related problem. Try adding the option on both server and client: `--ssl-cipher=AES128-SHA`. You can use any other suite present both sides in the output of `openssl ciphers HIGH`.

It's also possible that the MySQL client config file includes `ssl-verify-server-cert` option, if so remove it or (safer) use a domain name from server's certificate CN.

If it still fails you can:

1. Sniff your connection with tcpdump or Wireshark, look at TLS handshake.
2. Workaround the problem with *stunnel* or VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing certificates, it is all a wild guess.

But this one looks awfully relevant: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html

In short, client certificate CN MUST be different from CA CN.

The key words "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED", "SHALL", "SHALL NOT", "SHOULD", "SHOULD NOT", "RECOMMENDED",  "MAY", and "OPTIONAL" in this document are to be interpreted as described in [[RFC 2119]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119).